# One to many in Ef core Fk Viloation

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Ok I think I may have got this wrong in the model builder. I want the case which can be one case but inside that one case they can be many relationships.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RelationShips>()
              .HasOne<MISObject>(s => s.Case)
              .WithMany(g => g.RelationShip)
          .HasForeignKey(s => s.MisObjectId);
```

But when I attempt to save with the above

> DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See
> the inner exception for details. SqlException: The INSERT statement
> conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "FK_RelationShips_MISobject_MisObjectId". The conflict occurred in
> database "MISSystem", table "dbo.MISobject", column 'Id'. The
> statement has been terminated.

My MISObject has a collection of relationships as such

```
public class MISObject {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<RelationShips> RelationShip { get; set; }
}

public class RelationShips {
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public MISObject Case { get; set; }
}
```

Will the above not allow a one to many relationship basically one case could have 20 relationships but there could be many cases. But those 20 relationships should only belong to that case if that makes since.

I think I need to use hasmany but not to sure how in this context.

**Edit 2**

I think this might be what i need but im not sure how legal it is.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MISObject>()
 .HasMany(c => c.RelationShip);

modelBuilder.Entity<RelationShips>()
 .HasMany(c => c.PersonOfIntrests);

modelBuilder.Entity<POI>()
  .HasMany(c => c.PersonOfIntrestsPhotos)
  .WithOne(e => e.PersonOfIntrest);
```

Comment: Can you provide some snippet of you saving data to DB (creating the database entity)? If you want to allow create RelationShips without MISObject (I'm guessing based on error that's what's happening) you should make your foreign key as nullable

Comment: No a case will always have a relationship even if its just one realtionship but a realtionship could have many photos, or contact numbers for example

Answer (score 0):

To make this work with the FluentAPI, you need to completely define the navigation and use a foreign key:

```cs
public class Relationship {
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public int MisObjectId { get; set; } // <-- add foreign key ID
    
    public MisObject Case { get; set; }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MisObject>()
            .HasMany(o => o.Relationships)
            .WithOne(r => r.Case) // <-- add other endpoint
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.MisObjectId); // <-- add FK property
    }
}
```

Here is a fully working console project, that demonstrates these concepts:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class MisObject {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
    }

    public class Relationship {
        public int Id { get; set; }        
        public int MisObjectId { get; set; } // <-- add foreign key ID
        
        public MisObject Case { get; set; }
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MisObject> MisObjects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=.\MSSQL14;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=So62854210")
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        b => b
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MisObject>()
                .HasMany(o => o.Relationships)
                .WithOne(r => r.Case) // <-- add other endpoint
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.MisObjectId); // <-- add FK property

            // Technically not necessary, because this navigation has already been defined
            // in the previous line, but might be good practice anyway.
            modelBuilder.Entity<Relationship>()
                .HasOne(r => r.Case)
                .WithMany(o => o.Relationships)
                .HasForeignKey(r => r.MisObjectId);
        }
    }
    
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var newMisObject = new MisObject();
                var newRelationships = new[]
                {
                    new Relationship {Case = newMisObject},
                    new Relationship {Case = newMisObject},
                    new Relationship {Case = newMisObject},
                };

                context.MisObjects.Add(newMisObject);
                context.Relationships.AddRange(newRelationships);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var context = new Context())
            {
                var misObjects = context.MisObjects
                    .Include(o => o.Relationships)
                    .ToList();

                Debug.Assert(misObjects.Count == 1);
                Debug.Assert(misObjects[0].Relationships.Count == 3);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coincidentally, because the properties in this example follow EF Core naming conventions, you could even remove the `OnModelCreating()` method entirely here and the result would still work.
See [Relationships: Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions) for further information on that.

Comment: so this allows for many realtions to one case but does it allow for other relationships to other cases say I want to have many photos tied to multiple realtionshipsl.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. My answer demonstrates how to implement a one-to-many relationship, which is what you asked for in your question. If you want to implement  a many-to-many relationship, take a look at [Relationships: Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) or asked another question here on SO, or just present another example, of what you now want to accomplish.

Answer (score -1):

Just use convention there is no need to use fluent config for relationships:

```
public class MISObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RelationShips> RelationShip { get; set; }
    }
public class RelationShips
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CaseId { get; set; }
        public MISObject Case { get; set; }
    }
```

without any error, EF Core makes your Tables in the database.

Comment: No, @Mortaza Ghahremani is correct. If you **remove** your FluentAPI code from `OnModelCreating()`, then defining the model classes in this way should work by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions). Please don't just down vote an answer, if you don't understand it. Instead, try to inquire more about the answer first.

Comment: This is not a copy,I've tested it, at first test it then judges about that!